# iterative logarithm and one asymptotic example

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algorithms, logarithms, computer-science

we know about iterative logarithm like as [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm#:%7E:text=The%20iterated%20logarithm%20is%20closely%20related%20to%20the,its%20digits%20before%20reaching%20its%20digital%20root%20.).

> there are some typo in my note, so I update the question into:
> which of them is correct from asymptotic point of view? there is no need to proof, an intuitive idea is enough.

$n\log^*_n = \log^*(n^n)$

$\log^*n = \log^*(n^n)$

Is there a big typo in my notes or really this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log^*(n^n)=\log^*(n\log(n))+1=\log^*(\log(n)+\log(\log(n)))+2\\\sim \log^*(\log(n))+2=\log^*(n)+1\sim\log^*(n).$$

On the other hand,

$$\log^*(n^n)\sim n\log^*(n)$$ cannot be true, as the iterated logarithm is strongly sublinear.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: non-linearity !